# mod_cache returns "broken expires header"

Tags: tomcat, caching, apache2, magnolia, ajp

I am using apache2 as a `loadbalancer` and `frontend-proxy` in front of a tomcat server, connected via `mod_ajp`. Now, I would like to add Caching.

Unfortunately, the tomcat server's application sends back a lot of headers, which according to the RFC prevent the caching like `pragma: no-cache`, etc. But the main problem is an error message:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 09:44:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
X-Magnolia-Registration: Registered
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=xxxxxxx; Path=/form-cms/; Secure; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 09:44:33 GMT
Content-Language: en
X-Cache: MISS from fqdn.example.com
X-Cache-Detail: "Broken expires header: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" from fqdn.example.com
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

The cache config looks like this:

```
CacheRoot "/var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk"
CacheDirLevels 2
CacheDirLength 1
CacheMaxExpire 60
CacheDefaultExpire 60

CacheHeader on
CacheDetailHeader on

CacheIgnoreHeaders Expires
CacheIgnoreCacheControl on

CacheStoreNoStore On
CacheStorePrivat On

CacheQuickHandler off
<LocationMatch "^/my-app/.*">
    CacheEnable disk
</LocationMatch>
```

I am at a loss on how to solve this problem and cannot change the behaviour of the app on the tomcat server. I tried to unset the expires-header via mod_headers, but to no avail.

Any Ideas?

Comment: From the tags I assume you use Magnolia CMS. In such case, the problem could (I am not 100% sure) be conflict between cache headers from Magnolia and Apache - Magnolia implements advanced caching algorithms (see [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Cache+core)), so there is IMHO no need to put yet another cache in front of it. On the contrary, it could lead to quite unexpected behavior, in both the additional cache **and** Magnolia.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Unfortunately, our Magnolia 5.4 does not cache html templates correctly. We are in the process of checking with the magnolia support, if this is even possible - therefore the apache-cache in the apache load-balancer. I was able to solve the problem with nginx a few days ago, but since the client has everything on apache, I have no choice other than to solve it with apache - which I did, see accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Magnolia is returning a resource and would like to inform the browser, that it should not be cached, it is setting several headers: `pragma: no-cache`, `cache-control: no-store`, and an `Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT` header.

Since the first unix timestamp is 01/01/1970 12:00:00 am, the mod_cache apache module does give a `broken expires header` message.

The solution was to change the BrowserPolicy setting of Magnolia to include a FixedDuration expires header, but not to cache anything else.